# Google Maps API v 3: Heatmap Creation Issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I am trying to work with the google.maps.visualization library.  I have included the library in my code and all that, and most of it seems to be working, but when I get to the point of creating the heatmap, I get an error about 'Invalid value at position 96677: [object Object]'.  I am not sure what this problem is about, but the error report includes a line of the Google API code:

```
var c;
M(b,function(b,e){
    try{
        a(b)||(c="Invalid value at position "+(e+(": "+b)))
    }catch(f){
        c="Error in element at position "+(e+(": ("+(f[Pb]+")")))}});c&&aa(ja(c));return j
    }
}
```

I looked through the API code a bit, but it's pretty difficult to find anything useful in there.  The code I am using to create the heatmap layer is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../Yield/getYieldData.php",
    success: function(text) {
        var data;
//      var yieldPoints = new google.maps.MVCArray();
        var yieldPoints = [];

        try{
            data = $.parseJSON(text);
        } catch (e) {
            alert("ERROR: " + e);
        }

        for(i=0; i < data.points.length; i++) {
//          yieldPoints.push({ location: new google.maps.LatLng(data.points[i].lat, data.points[i].lon), weight: data.points[i].yield });
            yieldPoints[i] = { location: new google.maps.LatLng(data.points[i].lat, data.points[i].lon), weight: data.points[i].yield };
        }
        var heatMap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ data: yieldPoints });
        heatMap.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

I'm not sure where the problem is coming from here, but I used the Google API documentation as a template, as found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/layers#JSHeatMaps (about a third of the way down the page, under the heading 'Adding Weighted Data Points').  As you can see, I also attempted to create the array as an MVCArray, as described in that documentation, but that didn't change anything.  In case it's relevant, here's a short sample of the JSON data that is being received from the 'getYieldData.php' call:

`{"points":[{"lat":"38.1513366000","lon":"-97.4341659000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1513748000","lon":"-97.4341125000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1513938000","lon":"-97.4341125000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1493263000","lon":"-97.4339447000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1493339000","lon":"-97.4339447000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1493377000","lon":"-97.4339447000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1483650000","lon":"-97.4358291000","yield":"0"},{"lat":"38.1484031000","lon":"-97.4358062000","yield":"0"},`

Hopefully this is enough info for someone to see what the problem is- any help at all would be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Quick update: I tried dropping the last element of the array, and got the same error for position 96676, so apparently it is going through the array in reverse and finding issue with the elements in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`weight` should be a `Number`,not a `String`. So you have 2 choices:

- avoid quotes in JSON:

  ```
  {"lat":"38.1513366000","lon":"-97.4341659000","yield":0}
                //no quote wraps    'yield' ------------^
  ```
- cast `yield` to `Number`:

  ```
  yieldPoints[i] = { 
             location: new google.maps.LatLng(data.points[i].lat, data.points[i].lon),
             weight: +data.points[i].yield };
  };                 ^----- plus('+') is the fastest way for converting string to number
  ```

Comment: Thanks- that was the problem.  I used parseFloat() instead of '+'  How much of a hit am I going to take in terms of speed?

Comment: @Crash I think, in your case speed differences will not be visible enough. So `parseFloat` is appropriate too.

Comment: @Engineer Hey I have came across this weird issue. For my first heatmap, the weight is String and the heatmap works. Then for my second heatmap, the heatmap only works when the weight is String. When I cast it to Number, the heatmap is not showing up. However, for the second heatmap, the 'heat' somehow is showing in square and it does not work with the gradient I set. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @hyperfkcb Be sure you are casting valid-number-string to number, or you will get NaN, undefined or null